# How do I undo a git rebase and redo as a git merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, undo-redo

I ran a git rebase on a branch and fixed all the conflicts, then realised for this particular branch I need to run git merge instead, to keep the history. Is there a way to "undo" the rebase but automatically reapply my fixes when running the git merge?

Comment: If you have `rerere.enabled` set to true, that should already happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Amber said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768537/how-do-i-undo-a-git-rebase-and-redo-as-a-git-merge#comment32931326_21768537), if you turned on rerere, git will have "re"corded your previous "re"solution (two of the three re's).  Then if you reset things to pre-rebase state and "git merge" it should "re"use them (the last "re").

But if not, it won't.

What to do then?  Assuming you're quite confident of your resolution :-) you could try this.

The original chain of commits (pre-rebase) is likely still pointed-to by `ORIG_HEAD`.  If not, find the old branch-tip in the reflogs.  Give it a label (branch or tag name), while also keeping a label on the post-rebase chain.  That is, we want to resurrect the old branch tip, and also keep the new branch tip.  (Exactly *why* should be obvious once you understand the rest of this.)

I'll assume that in rebasing you modified commits `C` and `F` and dropped `D` and `E` entirely as no-longer needed.  Not that this is really matters.  `F'` is the only crucial commit.  The point is that commit `F'` captures the "final, all-resolved" version of the work-tree:

```
        C - D - E - F   <-- feature_orig
      /
A - B - G - H - I - J   <-- mainline
                      \
                        C' - F'  <-- feature
```

The above is what you can see after you do `git branch feature_orig ORIG_HEAD` (or recover the original tip from reflogs and use that to create `feature_orig`).

What you want now (per the original question) is a merge: either "merge feature into mainline" or "merge mainline into feature".  Except, you want it to happen on/with `feature_orig`, rather than the rebased `feature`.

One other question though: do you want to keep the `feature` branch around?  (If you're merging `mainline` into `feature` here, you probably do.  If merging feature into mainline, maybe not.  But at most, I suspect you will want to keep `feature_orig`, not the rebased line.)  Let's move one more branch name around now, to—I hope—make the picture clearer:

```
$ git branch -m feature feature_rebased
```

Now we have this:

```
        C - D - E - F   <-- feature_orig
      /
A - B - G - H - I - J   <-- mainline
                      \
                        C' - F'  <-- feature_rebased
```

Now for the merge.  Get onto the branch you want the merge commit to show up in:

```
$ git checkout ...
```

(I don't know which branch this is, `feature_orig` or `mainline`!)

Then do a merge, ignoring the result and not committing:

```
$ git merge --no-commit ...
```

(whichever branch you're merging-in).

Now just replace every single file with the version taken from commit `F'` (note, I'm assuming you're in your top level work directory here):

```
$ git rm -rf .; git checkout feature_rebased -- .
```

The `rm` step completely empties out the index, including all conflicts, and also the work tree.  Then the `checkout` step completely repopulates the index and work-tree using whatever is in commit `F'` (as obtained through the branch name `feature_rebased`).

You may now commit the merge, on whichever branch you're on.  For concreteness let's say you're on `feature_orig` and asked git to merge `mainline`.  After you `git commit` you should have this as your commit graph:

```
        C - D - E - F - M  <-- feature_orig
      /               /
A - B - G - H - I - J   <-- mainline
                      \
                        C' - F'  <-- feature_rebased
```

I think it's worth mentioning here that this is *just the commit graph*.  The contents of the *tree*—the files you get in your work-dir when you `git checkout` any of these commits—is determined by the contents of the index/staging-area at the time the commit was created.

That's *why* we can `git rm` everything and then `git checkout id -- .` to set up the contents of the merge commit.  All we do when we commit the merge is create a commit `M` whose parents are `F` and `J`, and whose contents are "whatever is now in the index".

(The *order* of the parents `F` and `J`, and to which branch-name the new commit ID is written, is determined by which branch we are on when we start and finish the `git merge` process.  If we are "on branch `feature_orig` then `F` is the first parent and `M` goes "on branch `feature_orig`".  If we are "on branch `mainline`, then `J` is the first parent and `M` goes "on branch `mainline`".  Also, of course, the prepared commit text, that you can edit before the commit happens, is a bit different.  But you can edit that to read whatever you like.)

---

At this point (or maybe even earlier) you can now rename `feature_orig` to `feature`, if you want to keep the name.  You can also delete branch `feature_rebased` as there's no need to save commits `C'` and `F'` any more.  In fact, we only really wanted to hang on to `F'` so that we could `git checkout` its tree—we could have deleted the branch as soon as we finished that `checkout`.