# Issue with git rebasing and merging that I need to rewind (not as simple as reverting)

Tags: git

So long story short I had a remote branch I was working on (my-remote-branch) that was failing some tests in the CI. I was told to rebase to master to fix this issue.

I did the following:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my-remote-branch
git rebase master
git push
```

At that point I got an error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

So next I did:

```
git pull --set-upstream-origin my-remote-branch
git push
```

This kind of just created a mess. My pull request now has a massive amount of commits (all the ones from master that occurred while I was working on this branch) so the history is all messed up and there's a misleading number of changed files for the pull request. This seems more complicated than a simple revert since I can't just revert back to one commit, all the commits are intertwined from master.

Apparently what I was **supposed** to do was this:

```
 git fetch origin master
 git rebase -I origin/master
 git push --force
```

Is there a way I can undo my mistake (undo the merge, remove commits from history in my branch only) so I can execute the step I was supposed to do?

[How do I undo a git rebase and redo as a git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768537/how-do-i-undo-a-git-rebase-and-redo-as-a-git-merge)

[Revert Merge and history "undo" from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986304/revert-merge-and-history-undo-from-git)

^These questions didn't help because I can't touch master in any way (besides pulling), and can't revert to a specific commit since master's commits are intertwined with mine.

Comment: This seems to be mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59034467/1256452 - pick one of the two, perhaps, to fix up with the right details, and delete the other?